# Circumcision once then blood drawn

Tags: brit-milah, blood

When a gentile is already circumcised and wants to convert to Judaism, blood has to be drawn from his penis. Why is this? What's the point?

Comment: You realize "drawing blood" here means just enough to see a drop, right?

Comment: @Shalom Possibly two drops, since there is a debate regarding the exact site where the drop needs to be extracted from.

Answer (score 2):

The drawing of blood, in the context of circumcision, forms a blood Covenant with God. As part of the conversion process, the person needs to join this blood Covenant, just like all other Jews who are part of this Covenant. If a person had their foreskin removed in the past, then the way to join this Covenant is by drawing blood from the same area where the circumcision would normally have been performed in the context of conversion.

Comment: Two examples might help illustrate: a Jew born without a foreskin (some sort of congenital defect) needs this done too, and a Jew who removed his foreskin using lasers or something such that no blood comes out does not fulfill the commandment.